# Getting parse error, unexpected T_ELSE(else), expecting '}'

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugins and its working fine but its showing parse error while using phpformatter.com.

error, unexpected T_ELSE(else), expecting '}'

Please do let me know how to remove the unexpected T_ELSE parse error.

```
<?php

class Bhuppu_Admin {

    static $short_code_added;
    public $errors;

    function __construct() {

        register_activation_hook(BHUUFU_PLUGIN_FILE, array(&$this, 'activation'));
        add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'enqueue'), 10);
        add_action('edit_user_profile', array(&$this, 'add_user_file_upload_fields'));
        add_action('edit_user_profile_update', array(&$this, 'save_user_file_upload_fields'));
        add_filter('upload_dir', array(&$this, 'user_upload_files_dir'));
        add_shortcode('list_user_files', array(&$this, 'user_uploaded_files_list'));
        add_filter('the_posts', array(&$this, 'conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles'));
        add_action('template_redirect', array(&$this, 'template_redirect'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_query-attachments', array(&$this, 'change_media_display'), 0);
        add_filter('wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', array(&$this, 'change_upload_media_display'),10,3);

        //ajax
        add_action('wp_ajax_deletefile', array(&$this, 'deletefile'));
        do_action('BHUUFU/init');
    }


    //setup on activation 
    public function activation() {
        //create sub directory
        $baseDir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/user-files/';
        wp_mkdir_p($baseDir);

        //create .htacess file
        $server_address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        $filename = $baseDir . '.htaccess';
        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            $file_handle = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Error: Unable to create .htaccess file");
            $content_string = "Options -Indexes\n";
            fwrite($file_handle, $content_string);
            $content_string = "Deny from all\n";
            fwrite($file_handle, $content_string);
            fclose($file_handle);
        }
    }

    //change upload directory
    public function user_upload_files_dir($upload) {
        //check if this a user-edit page
        $current_page = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $current_page_tmp = explode("?", $current_page);
        $current_page = $current_page_tmp[0];
        if ($current_page != "user-edit.php")
            return $upload;

        // check if it a async-upload request
        $referer = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if ($referer != "async-upload.php")
            return $upload;

        //get userid from http http_referer
        $p = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        parse_str($p["query"], $get);
        $user_id = $get['user_id'];

        //change upload directory to user-files/$user_id
        $baseDir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/user-files/';
        $baseUrl = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/user-files/';
        $upload['subdir'] = $user_id;
        $upload['path'] = $baseDir . $upload['subdir'];
        $upload['url'] = $baseUrl . $upload['subdir'];

        return $upload;
    }

    //Enqueue class assets\
    public function enqueue() {
        global $pagenow;
        if ($pagenow != "user-edit.php")
            return;
        // Enqueue styles
        wp_enqueue_style('bhuufu_admin_styles', BHUUFU_URL . '/assets/css/admin_styles.css');
        // Enqueue scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('bhuufu_repeatable-fields.js', BHUUFU_URL . '/assets/js/repeatable-fields.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('bhuufu_admin_script', BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/js/stb_admin.js');
        // Hook to add/remove files
        do_action('BHUUFU/assets/enqueue');
    }

    //conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles
    public function conditionally_add_scripts_and_styles($posts) {

        if (empty($posts))
            return $posts;
        $shortcode_found = false;
        foreach ($posts as $post) {

            if (stripos($post->post_content, '[list_user_files]') !== false) {
                $shortcode_found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($shortcode_found) {
            wp_enqueue_style('user-upload-css', BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/css/styles.css');
        }

        return $posts;
    }

    //user_file_upload_fields
    function add_user_file_upload_fields($user) {
        $bhu_uufef = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_file_uploads', true);
        wp_enqueue_media();
        ?>
        <h3><?php _e('File Uploads', 'wpcf7'); ?></h3>
        <div class="ff-repeatable">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e('Url', 'wpcf7'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php _e('Name', 'wpcf7'); ?></th>
                        <th><?php _e('Decsription', 'wpcf7'); ?></th>
                        <th><img alt="Add Row" class="ff-add-row" src="<?php echo BHUUFU_URL; ?>assets/images/add.png"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="ff-add-template" style="">
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_url_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_url" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_name_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_name" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_description_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_description" value="" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_id_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_id" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_oname_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_oname" value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_mime_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_mime" value="" />
                            <input class="button _unique_name_button" name="_unique_name_button" value="Select File" />
                            <img alt="Remove Row" class="ff-remove-row" src="<?php echo BHUUFU_URL; ?>assets/images/remove.png">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    if (isset($bhu_uufef['file_url']) && $extra_fields = array_filter($bhu_uufef['file_url'])) {
                        foreach ($extra_fields as $key => $value) {
                            echo'
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_url_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_url" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_url'][$key] . '" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_name_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_name" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_name'][$key] . '" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_description_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_description" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_description'][$key] . '" /></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_id_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_id" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_id'][$key] . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_oname_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_oname" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_oname'][$key] . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_mime_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_mime" value="' . $bhu_uufef['file_mime'][$key] . '" />
                        <input class="button _unique_name_button" name="_unique_name_button" value="Select File" />
                        <img alt="Remove Row" class="ff-remove-row" src="' . BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/images/remove.png">
                        </td>
                    </tr>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo'
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_url_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_url" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_name_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_name" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_description_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_description"  value="" /></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_id_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_id" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_oname_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_oname" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="bhuufu-user-uploads[file_mime_tmp][]" class="medium-text file_mime" value="" />
                        <input class="button _unique_name_button" name="_unique_name_button" value="Select File" />
                        <img alt="Remove Row" class="ff-remove-row" src="' . BHUUFU_URL . 'assets/images/remove.png">
                        </td> 
                    </tr>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>            
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    //user porfile fields save
        public function save_user_file_upload_fields($user_id) {
            if (isset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp']) && $extra_fields = array_filter($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp'])) {
                foreach ($extra_fields as $key => $value) {
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_name'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_name_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_description'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_description_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_id'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_id_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_oname'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_oname_tmp'][$key];
                    $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_mime'][] = $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_mime_tmp'][$key];
                }
            }
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_url_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_name_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_description_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_id_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_oname_tmp']);
            unset($_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']['file_mime_tmp']);
            update_usermeta($user_id, 'user_file_uploads', $_POST['bhuufu-user-uploads']);
        }

    //delete file
    public function deletefile() {
        global $wpdb;
        $file_id = $_REQUEST["file_id"];
        $user_id = $_REQUEST["user_id"];

        // Delete file
        $is_deleted = wp_delete_attachment($file_id);
        if ($is_deleted->ID) {
            $bhu_uufef = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_file_uploads', true);
            $key = array_search($file_id, $bhu_uufef['file_id']);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_url'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_name'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_description'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_id'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_oname'][$key]);
            unset($bhu_uufef['file_mime'][$key]);
            update_usermeta($user_id, 'user_file_uploads', $bhu_uufef);
            $result['status'] = "sucess";
        } else {
            $result['status'] = "fail";
        }

        echo json_encode($result);

        exit;
    }

    //user frontend to display the download list
    public function user_uploaded_files_list() {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            //list all files uploaded for user
            global $current_user;
            $bhu_uufef = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_file_uploads', true);
            if (isset($bhu_uufef['file_url']) && $extra_fields = array_filter($bhu_uufef['file_url'])) {
                $count = 1;
                $output .= <<< _RAMA
                            <tr>
                            <th>SN </th>
                            <th>File name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                            <th>Download</th>
                            </tr>
_RAMA;
                foreach ($extra_fields as $key => $value){
                    $wpnonce = wp_create_nonce("bhu_".$bhu_uufef['file_id'][$key]);
                    $size = size_format(filesize(get_attached_file($bhu_uufef['file_id'][$key])));
                       $download_link = "<a href='" . BHUUFU_URL . 'download.php?id=' . $bhu_uufef['file_id'][$key] . "&amp;wpnonce=$wpnonce' title='Download' target='_blank' class='small-btn'><img alt='Download' class='ff-add-row' src='http://www.rcmfire.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/download.png'></a>";
                    if ($count & 1)
                        $class = 'odd';
                    else
                        $class = 'even';
                    $output .= <<< _RAMA
                            <tr class="$class">
                            <td>$count</td>
                            <td>{$bhu_uufef['file_name'][$key]}</td>
                            <td>{$bhu_uufef['file_description'][$key]}</td>
                            <td>$size</td>
                            <td>$download_link</td>
                            </tr>
                _RAMA;
                    $count++;
                }
            } else {
                $output = "<tr><td colspan='5'><p>No current uploads</p></td></tr>";
            }
            $logout_url = '<a href="' . wp_logout_url(home_url()) . '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
            $table = <<< _RAMA
                        <table width="100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">Welcome $current_user->user_login</td>
                        <td>$logout_url</td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        $output
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
_RAMA;
            $final_html = "<div class='user-download-files' >" . $table . "</div>";
            return $final_html;
                } else {
                    $form = $_REQUEST['form'];
                    switch ($form) {
                        case 'lostpassword':
                            include_once BHUUFU_PATH . '/includes/user/forms/lostpassword-form.php';
                            break;
                        case 'resetpassword':
                            include_once BHUUFU_PATH . '/includes/user/forms/restpassword-form.php';
                            break;
                        default:
                            include_once BHUUFU_PATH . '/includes/user/forms/login-form.php';
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //to handle login,reset,new password
            public function template_redirect() {
                $do_process = $_REQUEST['do_process'];
                switch ($do_process) {
                    case 'lostpassword':
                        include_once BHUUFU_PATH . '/includes/user/process/lostpassword-process.php';
                        break;
                    case 'resetpassword':
                        include_once BHUUFU_PATH . '/includes/user/process/resetpassword-process.php';
                        break;
                    default:
                        include_once BHUUFU_PATH . '/includes/user/process/login-process.php';
                        break;
                }
            }

        //check password reset key
        public static function check_password_reset_key($key, $login) {
            global $wpdb;

            $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $key);

            if (empty($key) || !is_string($key))
                return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));

            if (empty($login) || !is_string($login))
                return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));

            $user = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_activation_key = %s AND user_login = %s", $key, $login));

            if (empty($user))
                return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));

            return $user;
        }

    //reset password
public static function reset_password($user, $new_pass) {

        wp_set_password($new_pass, $user->ID);
}

    //alter images display on miedia uploader
public function change_media_display() {
        //check if this a user-edit page
        $current_page = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $current_page_tmp = explode("?", $current_page);
        $current_page = $current_page_tmp[0];

        // check if it a async-upload request
        $referer = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        if ($current_page == "user-edit.php" && $referer == "admin-ajax.php") {

            if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) )
        wp_send_json_error();

            $query = isset($_REQUEST['query']) ? (array) $_REQUEST['query'] : array();
            $query = array_intersect_key($query, array_flip(array(
                's', 'order', 'orderby', 'posts_per_page', 'paged', 'post_mime_type',
                'post_parent', 'post__in', 'post__not_in',
                    )));

            $query['post_type'] = 'attachment';
            if (current_user_can(get_post_type_object('attachment')->cap->read_private_posts))
                $query['post_status'] = 'private';

            /**
             * Filter the arguments passed to WP_Query during an AJAX call for querying attachments.
             *
             * @since 3.7.0
             *
             * @param array $query An array of query variables. @see WP_Query::parse_query()
             */
            $query = apply_filters('ajax_query_attachments_args', $query);
            $query = new WP_Query($query);

            $posts = array_map('wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', $query->posts);
            $posts = array_filter($posts);
//            foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
//                $posts[$key]['type'] = 'images';
//            }
            wp_send_json_success($posts);
        }
    }

    //change upload media display
public function change_upload_media_display($response, $attachment, $meta) {
        //check if this a user-edit page
        $current_page = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $current_page_tmp = explode("?", $current_page);
        $current_page = $current_page_tmp[0];

        // check if it a async-upload request
        //$referer = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        if ($current_page == "user-edit.php") {
            //change image type
            if ( $response['type'] = "image" )
                $response['type'] = "images" ;

            //change attachment status to private
            if ($attachment->post_status = "inherit" ) {
                $attachment_change = array( 'ID' => $attachment->ID, 'post_status' => 'private' );
                wp_update_post( $attachment_change );
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }

}

new Bhuppu_Admin;
```

Comment: Isin't the error message obvious?

Comment: Use a IDE such phpstorm or netbeans (free) and problem solved.

Comment: phpformatter.com showing error, unexpected T_ELSE(else), expecting '}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possibly line 261, the `_RAMA` line needs to be unindented:

```
                        <td>$download_link</td>
                        </tr>
_RAMA;
                $count++;
```

When using heredoc syntax, the terminator needs to be the only thing on that line (no trailing spaces) and at the start of the line (no indentation).

The _RAMA was indented, so PHP didn't think the string ended and gobbled up lines after that as part of the string literal.

Use an IDE that syntax highlights to easily spot when a string is unexpectedly un-terminated:

[image: Note how the green "string" color goes past the _RAMA line]

Note how the green "string" color goes past the _RAMA line

Comment: Could you please let me know why the multi dimensional array showing only 139 files?